# Parsing environment variables into configuration yaml file

Tags: dask

I am using dask on the GFDL analysis cluster to analyze large climate model output.

I am trying to set my `temporary-directory` configuration to a temporary directory, which can change depending on the node I am logging with (it is always identified by the environmental variable `$TMPDIR`).

Is there a way to parse environment variables in the dask configuration files?

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Not as of today, but that could be done.  I recommend raising an issue on the Dask issue tracker.